# Кастомный ListView

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. Имеется код (сократил до рассматриваемых компонентов).
В коде идет парсинг статей с сайта, затем каждая статья помещается в массив `arr` и в `onPostExecute` загружается в `listview lv`: `lv.setAdapter(adapter);`. Тут проблем нет, все отлично. Хочу добавить время добавления статьи (тоже спарсеное соответственно) и отобразить в каждом списке `listview` справа ниже мелким шрифтом. Получается уже нужен кастомный `listview`. Вот тут то и начинаются проблемы. Ввиду моей малоопытности сам я новый адаптер не напишу, поэтому рассматривал примеры. Пробовал подстроить под себя вот [этот пример](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-listview-2-custom-listview/). Все вроде ничего, но только там подгружается из уже готовых массивов, пробовал поставить свой - ругается, что якобы не соответствуют типы (наверно потому что у меня не обычный массив, а коллекция `ArrayList<String>`). Может кто знает, подскажите пожалуйста как на этом примере в одном элементе `listview` отобразить сразу два `textview` из данного массива `arr`. В данном примере я еще не реализовал парсинг времени статьи, пускай будет два одинаковых `textview` (с текстом статьи), дальше под себя подшаманю. Заранее очень благодарен кто поможет.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Parser par;
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        par = new Parser();
        par.execute();

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, arr);
    }

    class Parser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void ... params) {

            Document doc = null;

            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.site.ru").get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (doc != null) {
                Elements text2 = doc.select("div.entry-content");
                for (Element temp : text2) {
                    arr.add(temp.text().replaceAll("—", "\n —"));
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorText"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:divider="@color/colorDivider"
    android:typeface="serif" >
</TextView>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:title="@string/app_name">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_next"
        android:choiceMode="none"
        android:scrollingCache="true"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:divider="@color/colorDivider"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:stackFromBottom="false"
        android:smoothScrollbar="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:padding="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: А может имеет смысл заменить ListView на RecyclerView ?

Comment: @NikolayRomanov, почитал про RecyclerView, надеялся что там попроще... Такой же дремучий лес...

Comment: Отметьте правильный ответ или добавьте свой если Вам не помог ни один из текущих

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для меня, как для новичка, самым понятным все же оказался [этот пример](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-listview-2-custom-listview/).
Правда там используются заранее проинициализированные массивы `String []`, у меня же была коллекция `ArrayList<String>`, инициализирующаяся в процессе работы приложения через `Jsoup`. Заменив соответствующие типы и поля `setText()` все заработало! Спасибо за подсказки.

Answer (score 4):

Если проблема в том что  бы вместо одного TextView их  было два, то ваш 
**item.xml** должен быть примерно таким:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/title_layout_mainToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Плюс кастомный адаптер:

```
public class BoxAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  Context ctx;
  LayoutInflater lInflater;
  ArrayList<Product> objects;

  BoxAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> products) {
    ctx = context;
    objects = products;
    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  }

  // кол-во элементов
  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
  }

  // элемент по позиции
  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
  }

  // id по позиции
  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  // пункт списка
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // используем созданные, но не используемые view
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
      view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    }

    Product p = getProduct(position);

      //заполнение TextView данными
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_frist)).setText(p.name);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_second)).setText(p.price + "");

    return view;
  }

  // товар по позиции
  Product getProduct(int position) {
    return ((Product) getItem(position));
  }

}
```

Вместо объекта Product у вас может быть свой объект который содержит данные для заполнения айтема.

В итоге получаеться что:

1. вы создаете сложный(больше одной вьюхи) элемент списка  -> **item.xml**
2. создаете кастомный адаптер, в котором инфлейтите айтемы и для каждого айтема берете из списка объект с данными и заполняете этими данными вьюхи в айтеме.

Comment: Да, я знаю) Проблема написать адаптер, который бы из коллекции `ArrayList<String> arr` заполнит оба поля.

Comment: я добавил адаптер, код я не запускал, но в целом это то что вам нужно!

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю вашу задачу, то я не знаю что может быть проще...